# About [Time] for a cleanup?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

I have a time related problem that I am trying to solve so was looking through the various [time](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) related tags and descriptions. I found them rather contradictory and several aspects of them circular/redundant. To be fair the main tag *was* last edited 3 years ago.

- I'm not sure on the meta tag process. So this question, that was prompted by one tag, may need to be split up for each issue.

The excerpt for [time](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) states:

> For questions about the passage or measurement of time or how it can be affected, including traveling back and forth in it.

With the more detailed description stating:

> This tag is for questions about the effects of time on a civilization, or vice-versa. If the question involves space as well - typically as the result of relativistic effects - use the space-time tag.
>
> Also consider the time-travel tag, if time travel is involved.

---

- first off, we have [time-keeping](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-keeping) and synonym [calender](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calender) for the measurement of time. So can that not be removed from the [time](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) tag?

  - I just found 1 question using the [time-measurement](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-measurement) which should be removed or made a synonym of [time-keeping](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-keeping).
- secondly, we have [time-travel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel) and several *methods* covering all time-travel aspects. Should this not be removed from the [time](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) tag?
- thirdly, the [space-time](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-time) description is actually blank and has 0 tagged questions. It is also mentioned in [space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space) but I think it can either be removed or be made a synonym for [spacetime-dimensions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacetime-dimensions) which has 72 questions?

> Concerning dimensions of space and time, whether our 3-space + 1-time or other dimensions.
>
> This tag should be used in questions concerning various dimensions of space and time, where interaction between different space-time dimensions occurs, space-time dimensions other than 3+1 are involved, or the question concerns the space-time dimensions themselves

---

**I am suggesting** a clean-up of the [time](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) by making it just about the passage of standard time. 
With directions to the other tags such as [time-keeping](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-keeping)[time-travel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel)[spacetime-dimensions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacetime-dimensions).

I'm not sure if a further **new tag** should be created for [time-manipulation] for questions about non-standard time ie speeding up/slowing down/stopping/time-bubbles etc without actually time-travelling or reaching faster-than-light speeds, or if this would actually fall under the scope of the already existing [spacetime-dimensions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacetime-dimensions)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the suggestion of cleaning up [time](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time).

[space-time](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-time) doesn't exist. You can see that when searching the [tags](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags) for it. When I create a random tag with the tag markdown it automatically points to an empty page. For example [glarnak-the-great](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glarnak-the-great) is valid tag markdown - but there is no such tag, so it will point to a similar site as [space-time](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-time). This means there is nothing to worry about with that tag - we should just remove the old reference in the [space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space) tag wiki.

I think the new tag is useful and we should add it - preferrably directly with a tag wiki that describes its usage.

Comment: I made a suggested edit on the space tag wiki to change from space-time to spacetime-dimensions. I edited the time-measurement tag on the one question to time-keeping (I don't have enough required tag rep to create a synonym). I've left the time tag alone for now until there is more feedback :)